# Using inputs in HTML to run functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I am working on a stock market simulator using HTML and JS. I have a api [here](http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/) that gets current stock prices. Here is my HTML http://pastebin.com/ymcGKtin Sorry about pastebin not very good at formatting for SO. But in the function add stock I am trying to push the submitted form `stock`to the array `stocks`. However I have run into a problem trying to figure out how to get the submitted form `stock` and push it to the array. If I could get some pointers on how to do this it would be appricated. To be specific I would like help on getting the attribute `stock` pushed to the array `Stocks`. Ideas?

```js
var Market = {};
var Stocks = [];


Market.getQuote = function(symbol, fCallback){
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.fCallback = fCallback;
    this.DATA_SRC = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp";
    this.makeRequest();
}
Market.getQuote.handleSuccess = function(jsonResult){
    this.fCallback(jsonResult);
}
Market.getQuote.handleError = function(jsonResult){
    console.error(jsonResult);
}
Market.makeRequest = function () {
    //Abort any open requests
    if (this.xhr) { this.xhr.abort(); }
    //Start a new request
    this.xhr = $.ajax({
        data: { symbol: this.symbol },
        url: this.DATA_SRC,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: this.handleSuccess,
        error: this.handleError,
        context: this
    });
};
function addStock(){
   alert("derp");
  // Stocks.push(ele.getAttribute)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stock Market Game PRE ALPHA BETA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit = "addStock()">
        <input type="text" name="stock" value =""><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Get Price">
    </form>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: get the input box using `document.getElementBy...`, then get it's value (.value)

Comment: Note: your script element, before the doctype, makes your whole page invalid. `<script>` is required to be inside the `<head>` in this case. Also, you declare you are using the xmlns namespace. No you're not. Remove that part.

Comment: It is out of order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JQuery you could use [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on the form-object (`this` in the `onsubmit`-handler):

```
...
    function addStock(form){
        var value = $(form).find('input[name="stock"]').val();
        alert(value);
        Stocks.push(value);

        //prevents a submit of the form
        return false;
    }

</SCRIPT>
<form onsubmit = "return addStock(this);">
    <input type="text" name="stock" value =""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Price">
</form>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the `addStock()` function to use the [form element collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) method.

```
function addStock(){
    var xForm = document.forms[0];
    var xField = xForm.elements[0];
    alert("Stock: "+xField.value);
    Stocks.push(xField.value);
    console.log(Stocks);

 }
```

```js
var Market = {};
var Stocks = [];


Market.getQuote = function(symbol, fCallback) {
  this.symbol = symbol;
  this.fCallback = fCallback;
  this.DATA_SRC = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp";
  this.makeRequest();
}
Market.getQuote.handleSuccess = function(jsonResult) {
  this.fCallback(jsonResult);
}
Market.getQuote.handleError = function(jsonResult) {
  console.error(jsonResult);
}
Market.makeRequest = function() {
  //Abort any open requests
  if (this.xhr) {
    this.xhr.abort();
  }
  //Start a new request
  this.xhr = $.ajax({
    data: {
      symbol: this.symbol
    },
    url: this.DATA_SRC,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: this.handleSuccess,
    error: this.handleError,
    context: this
  });
};

function addStock() {
  var xForm = document.forms[0];
  var xField = xForm.elements[0];
  alert("Stock: " + xField.value);
  Stocks.push(xField.value);
  console.log(Stocks);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Stock Market Game PRE ALPHA BETA</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="addStock()">
    <input type="text" name="stock" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Price">
  </form>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```